# CNN Model is not updated after the epochs: Tensorflow

Tags: validation, tensorflow, training-data

I was building a CNN model for source separation. The training data are fed into the network as batches and validation loss is calculated per epoch. However, I could see that the validation loss remains the same. I suspect that the model is not updated after every epoch but not sure how as I can see that the training loss is changing and the optimizer is run for every batch. Here is the training function:

```
def train():
    # Model
    model = Model()

    # Loss, Optimizer
     global_step = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int32, trainable=False, name='global_step')

    loss_fn = model.loss()
    optimizer =  tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=TrainConfig.LR).minimize(loss_fn, global_step=global_step)

    with tf.Session(config=TrainConfig.session_conf) as sess:

        # Initialized, Load state
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        # Input source
        data = Data(TrainConfig.DATA_PATH)

        loss = Diff()
        mixed_wav, src1_wav, src2_wav, numBatch = data.load_wavs()#load all train wavs
        data = Data(ValidConfig.DATA_PATH)
        mixed_val_wav, src1_val_wav, src2_val_wav, numBatch2 = data.load_wavs()#give path argument, change in data.py

        for step in range(global_step.eval(), TrainConfig.FINAL_STEP):#epoch
            batch = 0

            #code for shuffling the data

            for batch in range(0, numBatch):#batch         

                #data is formatted to batchwise
                l, _, _ = sess.run([loss_fn, optimizer, _],
                                     feed_dict={model.x_mixed: mixed_batch, model.x_mixed_spec: mixed_batch_spec, model.y_src1: src1_batch, model.y_src2: src2_batch}) #needed to give mixed and original spectra and also mixed signal to the model

                loss.update(l)
                print('Train losses: step={}\td_loss={:2.2f}\tloss={}'.format(batch, loss.diff * 100, loss.value))

            #after the epoch, validation data formatting
            #calculation of validation loss
            lval = sess.run(loss_fn, feed_dict={model.x_mixed: mixed_val_batch, model.x_mixed_spec: mixed_val_batch_spec, model.y_src1: src1_val_batch, model.y_src2: src2_val_batch})


            print('validation loss epoch={}\tloss={}'.format(step, lval))
```

And here is the output

Train losses: step=0    d_loss=0.00 loss=5536927.0

Train losses: step=1    d_loss=-17.21   loss=4583803.5

Train losses: step=2    d_loss=11.89    loss=5128806.5

Train losses: step=3    d_loss=29.56    loss=6644758.5

---

Train losses: step=569  d_loss=-28.71   loss=5554282.0

validation loss epoch=0 loss=67791024.0

Train losses: step=0    d_loss=4.14 loss=5784481.5

Train losses: step=1    d_loss=-13.78   loss=4987227.0

---

Train losses: step=568  d_loss=46.64    loss=6187295.0

Train losses: step=569  d_loss=-15.51   loss=5227377.0

validation loss epoch=1 loss=67791024.0

Train losses: step=0    d_loss=-1.49    loss=5149379.0

Train losses: step=1    d_loss=-17.81   loss=4232363.0

---

Would be great if someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the outputs for the validation. The problem might be that your outputs for validation are constant (all 0, or other value). It's very probable, as you training loss is not decreasing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not think about it. The validation outputs were all zeros.